# Accessing Nested Map of Type map[string]interface{} in Golang

Tags: json, dictionary, go, interface

So I'm trying to parse a JSON response. It can be multiple levels deep. This is what I did:

```
var result map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(apiResponse, &result)
```

**Firstly, is this the right way to do it?**

Lets say the response was as follows:

```
{
  "args": {
            "foo": "bar"
          }
}
```

To access key `foo`, I saw a [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/D2cz2Af4vE) doing this:

```
result["args"].(map[string]interface{})["foo"]
```

Here, what is the `.()` notation? Is this correct?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The notation `x.(T)` is called a [Type Assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

> For an expression `x` of interface type and a type `T`, the primary expression `x.(T)` asserts that `x` is not `nil` and that the value stored in `x` is of type `T`.

Your example:

```
result["args"].(map[string]interface{})["foo"]
```

It means that the value of your `results` map associated with key `"args"` is of type `map[string]interface{}` (another map with `string` keys and any values). And you want to access the element of that map associated with the key `"foo"`.

If you know noting about the input JSON format, then yes, you have to use a generic `map[string]interface{}` type to process it. If you know the exact structure of the input JSON, you can create a `struct` to match the expected fields, and doing so you can unmarshal a JSON text into a value of your custom `struct` type, for example:

```
type Point struct {
    Name string
    X, Y int
}

func main() {
    in := `{"Name":"center","X":2,"Y":3}`

    pt := Point{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(in), &pt)

    fmt.Printf("Result: %+v", pt)
}
```

Output:

```
Result: {Name:center X:2 Y:3}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/9P3kdq6Cg0).

### Modeling your input

Your current JSON input could be modelled with this type:

```
type Data struct {
    Args struct {
        Foo string
    }
}
```

And accessing `Foo` (try it on the [Go Playground)](http://play.golang.org/p/80dWvpwUsH):

```
d := Data{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(in), &d)
fmt.Println("Foo:", d.Args.Foo)
```

Comment: Also, if `foo` is of type `interface{}`, what's the difference between doing `string(foo)` and `foo.(string)`?

Comment: @SreejithRamakrishnan I don't think there is any significant performance hit as if you use a custom `struct`, it is also populated via reflection.

Comment: @SreejithRamakrishnan And yes, there is difference between `stirng(foo)` and `foo.(string)`. First is a _conversion_, the latter is a _type assertion_. Type assersion can only be used on _interface types_ (`interface{}` is an empty interface which qualifies), and for the rules of conversion read the spec: [Conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). If your case you can't use conversion only type assertion.

Answer (score 12):

`struct` is the best option, but if you insist, you can add a type declaration for a map, then you can add methods to help
with the type assertions:

```
package main
import "encoding/json"

type dict map[string]interface{}

func (d dict) d(k string) dict {
   return d[k].(map[string]interface{})
}

func (d dict) s(k string) string {
   return d[k].(string)
}

func main() {
   apiResponse := []byte(`{"args": {"foo": "bar"}}`)
   var result dict
   json.Unmarshal(apiResponse, &result)
   foo := result.d("args").s("foo")
   println(foo == "bar")
}
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations

Comment: Helper method for slice:
`func (d dict) a(k string) []interface{} {
 return d[k].([]interface{})
}`