# How to parse map[string]interface{} passed in context

Tags: go, parsing

**Problem**

I wish to add `variable` to the request context in a **Middleware**

```golang
fmt.Println(variable) // => map[key1:some text key2:[str1] key3:1234567890]
```

Then, access `value.keyx` in my **Route handler**

```golang
v := variable[key1]
fmt.Prinln(v) // => some text

// AnotherFunction requires a `string`
AnotherFunction(v)
```

---

**Middleware**

I add this variable to a context in a middleware such as:

```golang
// Middleware function
...
fmt.Println(variable) // => map[key1:some text key2:[str1] key3:1234567890]
fmt.Println(variable["key1"]) // => some text
ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "var", variable)
```

which works fine.

---

**Route Handler**

Then, in my route handler I am able to access the context by doing

```golang
values := r.Context().Value("var")

fmt.Println(values) // => map[key1:some text key2:[str1] key3:1234567890]
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(values)) // => map[string]interface {}
```

The issue is when I try to access the properties inside `values`

---

**Attempts**

1. I tried the same I did in **Middleware**

```golang
fmt.Println(values["key1"]) // => invalid operation: cannot index claims (variable of type interface{})
```

2. I investigated [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28807170/11061371) but `value` is not a JSON object
3. Doing a cast I am able to access `"key1"`. BUT, it is not accepted by `AnotherFunction(s string)` which requires a `string`.

```golang
values := r.Context().Value("var")
casted := values.(map[string]interface{})

keyValue := casted["key1"]

fmt.Println(keyValue) // => some text
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(keyValue)) // => string

// AnotherFunction requires a string input
AnotherFunction(keyValue) // => cannot use keyValue (variable of type interface{}) as string value in argument to AnotherFunction
```

So, I do another cast to work

```golang
values := r.Context().Value("var")
casted := values.(map[string]interface{})

keyValue := casted["key1"].(string) // <= Another cast

fmt.Println(keyValue) // => some text
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(keyValue)) // => string

// AnotherFunction requires a string input
AnotherFunction(keyValue) // => OK
```

I'm convinced that there's another more correct way to do it.

Comment: *"I'm convinced that there's another more correct way to do it."* -- There isn't, not if you start out with the original type that you stored in the context. If you don't like doing so many type assertions then you should *not* be using `map[string]interface{}` to hold the data.

Comment: Thanks. The incoming variable `map[string]interface{}` (that is added in the context) is an output from a function that generates some fields dynamically. It would also be quite cumbersome to rearrange it otherwise.

Comment: You're exactly right Kmelow, cumbersome is what `map[string]interface{}` is. Often it is chosen out of convenience only for it to have the opposite effect down the road.