# Golang iterate over nested struct

Tags: json, go

i want to iterate over a nested json struct in golang. The issue is, i do not exactly know how nested the structure will be, becuase there are multiple jsons. In this case for example the output should be:
"available": false
"type": "foo"
"name": "foo"
"street": "foo"
....

Is that possible?

```
{
    "informations": {
        "available": false,
        "provide": {
            "informations": {
                "customer": {
                    "type": "foo",
                    "address": {
                        "name": "foo",
                        "street": "foo",
                        "zipcode": "123",
                        "city": "foo"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems do you have? Post your attempt, a [mcve].

Comment: Very much. I just honestly think it's not that cool until now. :(

Comment: The usual approach is to unmarshal the document to a (nested) `map[string]interface{}` and then iterate over them, starting from the topmost (of course) and [type-asserting](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) the values based on the key (or "the path" formed by the key nesting) or [type-switching](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) on the values.

Comment: This could give you some hints: <https://play.golang.org/p/Deu7ZAdYO13>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a `map[string]interface{}`. Because, as you said that you don't know exactly the structure of the JSON. But, again, you need to know the JSON structure each time while extracting data. Also, you need to do type assertion for inner `map[string]interface{}`. You can look at the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28807170/8962366) for type assertion.

Here's the example code that I wrote:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var j = `{
    "informations": {
        "available": false,
        "provide": {
            "informations": {
                "customer": {
                    "type": "foo",
                    "address": {
                        "name": "foo",
                        "street": "foo",
                        "zipcode": "123",
                        "city": "foo"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

func main() {
    var data map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(data["informations"])
    information := data["informations"]
    provide := information.(map[string]interface{})["provide"]
    fmt.Println(provide)
}
```

Output will be:

```
map[available:false provide:map[informations:map[customer:map[address:map[city:foo name:foo street:foo zipcode:123] type:foo]]]]
map[informations:map[customer:map[address:map[city:foo name:foo street:foo zipcode:123] type:foo]]]
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gqmxXrtKGT_X)